# infusionsoft contact field query with python

Tags: python-3.x, infusionsoft

I know how to connect to Infusionsoft with Python 3 and how to process the following simple example:

```
#Set up the contact data we want to add
contact = {}; #blank dictionary
contact[“FirstName”] = “John”;
contact[“LastName”] = “Doe”;
contact[“Email”] = "john@doe.com";
contact[“Company”] = “ACME”;
```

But how do I mass update the WHOLE database? e.g. If I want to update ALL The Phone1 fields with an extra bit of code using IF statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Infusionsoft API you can only update contacts data one by one, sending a separate request per contact. Exact request depends on which type of API you use: [REST](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/rest/#!/Contact/updateContactUsingPATCH) or [XML-RPC](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/xml-rpc/#contact-update-a-contact)

Comment: Many thanks Yuga. Does that mean that I will have to pull each individual contact and then update their fields individually? What would be the best way to select each field using Python?

Comment: Basically, yes. But exact approach depends on your exact situation. Either you may load all contacts first and then send updated values for each of the contact. Or you may load contacts by known fields values right away, to have only the contacts matching your criteria. After that again, send update request per each contact, knowing its ID needed for the request.